# Should answers agreeing with other answers be added as a comment or edit instead

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I have seen many answers that agree with the first answer supplied, and simply add an extra bit of information ([see this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/whats-the-easiest-process-for-cutting-bathroom-flooring-tiles-to-fit-complex-doo), [and this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/686/covering-old-baseboard-skirting), [and this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/is-it-worth-having-two-locks-in-exterior-doors)).  Should these answers simply be added as a comment to the first answer, or is it good to have multiple answers that are relatively the same.

Alternatively could users who want to supply an extra bit of info just edit the answer they agree with (given they have enough rep), or is it better to not edit others answers?

If similar answers should be added as comments or edits, should this be detailed in the faq section?

Comment: I'm hesitant to edit others' answers unless it's a community wiki. The few cases I've done it, I didn't actually add content, mostly just formatting.

Comment: Is it considered rude to leave a comment on these types of answers suggesting that they should be comments instead?

Comment: @Doresoom - I'm hesitant to edit other people's answers as well, but as much as I generally avoid doing it, I think that's the way it's "supposed to work".

Answer (score 11):

I would say extra information should be added as a comment, and the original poster can choose to add it as an edit to their post.

I think this would allow users searching for answers to a similar problem, to not have to read all the answer. This would also make accepted or top voted answers better and more informative.

Comment: Agreed, this is the norm for other sites in the SE family.

Comment: Seconded. That's what makes this NOT a forum.

Answer (score 4):

If you just have a correction or a little bit of extra information to add to an already substantial answer, make a comment.  The author of the answer can then choose to edit their post to incorporate your suggestion.

If what you add is substantial, make a new answer, but make sure your new answer stands on its own.  Generally, you should not assume that the reader has read or will read the other answers.  After all, yours might be the accepted or top-voted answer, and an answer that existed before yours may be pushed far down, even to page two, or deleted.  Instead, make a new answer that is as full and good as possible.  It's OK to restate something that has already been pointed out in another answer, especially if it's something you knew already or could have learned as part of your research for answering the question.  On the other hand, you shouldn't copy other answers verbatim or pretend that others' case studies and experiences are your own.  If necessary, you can summarize and link to another answer that has an interesting case study, just as you would to an external website.

Comment: Is it considered rude to leave a comment on these types of answers suggesting that they should be comments instead?